# In a completely diffused light, would a battered paper sheet look different from the smooth sheet?

Tags: optics

Let's say we are in some fog that delivers mostly equal amount of light from every direction, and we have two sheets of paper, one smooth and another slightly battered so that is has uneven surface.

Under these conditions, would we be able to tell from the sight which sheet is battered (has a surface profile)? If there is some study, equation, model for further reading on these conditions, I would be happy to get the hints for further digging.

We assume that the sheets are too large to see the edges (they disappear in the fog). Otherwise the sheets are close enough that we could see, say, drawings on them through the fog. However there are no any markings on the sheets, just a difference in they 3D surface (flat and battered). We can approach close to the sheets, just cannot touch.

I understand that surface would be easily visible if we add some direct light source.

Comment: In theory you could see a difference because the rough sheet has distance differences to your eye position.  Also the perfect flat sheet's corners should look dimmer than the centre due to distance as well (1/r^2).

Comment: This is probably my answer, and I would accept it if correct.

Comment: If the light gets dim enough then shot noise would overwhelm the 1/r^2 and if would not be visible.

Comment: Thing brings up memories of a brief (few minutes) period of whiteout I experienced on a skiing trip. It is difficult to manage bumps you can't discern.